# Subversion : possible conflcts between svn+ssh/svnserve and webdav?

Tags: svn, svnserve

I have a subversion server wich severals repositories wich are accessible via https/webdav. We need to allow svn+ssh access too on the same repositories. Is this a problem to have both access from svnserve and from webdav at the same time?
Repositories use bdb of fsfs.

Answer (score 1):

You may likely run into issues with file permissions, because one svn+ssh user will eventually commit with a umask with insufficient permissions, effectively preventing the webserver from writing and thus breaking DAV. I usually advocate to use only one access method, with DAV being the preferred one, because it cleanly abstracts the permission complex away from filesystem and local users into the webserver.